# grails cdn-asset-pipeline plugin

Tags: spring, grails

We are currently using grails cdn-asset-pipeline plugin. For pushing our assets into s3. The cdn-asset-pipeline plugin use loadApp() inside _AssetCdn.groovy. Which causes JNDI issues. The JNDI is available in our production tomcat. **When we use grails run-app we are able to run our app without issues**. Can you let me know what changes we can do to overcome this issue.

_AssetCdn.groovy:

```
target(loadConfig: "Load CDN assets config") {
depends(compile, parseArguments)

if (argsMap['help']) {
    println USAGE
    exit 0
}
loadApp()
configureApp()
initKarman()
providers = []

def cdnAssetsConfig = grailsApp.config.grails.assets?.cdn
providers = cdnAssetsConfig.providers ?: []

if (!providers) {
    def providerObject = [:]
    providerObject.provider = argsMap['provider'] ?: cdnAssetsConfig?.provider ?: ''
    providerObject.directory = argsMap['directory'] ?: cdnAssetsConfig?.directory ?: ''
    providerObject.accessKey = argsMap['access-key'] ?: cdnAssetsConfig?.accessKey ?: ''
    providerObject.secretKey = argsMap['secret-key'] ?: cdnAssetsConfig?.secretKey ?: ''
    providerObject.region = argsMap['region'] ?: cdnAssetsConfig?.region ?: ''
    providers << providerObject
}
```

When we run, the below command before building the war

**grails asset-cdn-push --provider=S3 --directory="my directory" --gzip=true --storage-path="storage path" --access-key="access key" --secret-key="secret key"**

The Error:

| Error executing script AssetCdnPush: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_bonita' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_bonita': Cannot resolve reference to
 bean 'sessionFactory_bonita' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_bonita': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource_bonita' while setting bean property 'dataSource
'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource_bonita': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy_bonita' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy_bonita': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied_bonita' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied_bonita': Invocatio
n of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/bonitaDS] not bound; 2 bindings: [bonitaSequenceManagerDS,bonitaDS]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied_bonita': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/bonitaDS] not bound; 2 bindings: [bonitaSequenceManagerDS,
bonitaDS]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied_bonita': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/bonitaDS] not bound; 2 bindings: [bonitaSequenceManagerDS,
bonitaDS]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied_bonita': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/bonitaDS] not bound; 2 bindings: [bonitaSequenceManagerDS,
bonitaDS] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)